# Prove or disprove: $\sum a_n$ convergent, where $a_n=2\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}-\sqrt{n+1}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let $a_n=2\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}-\sqrt{n+1}$. Show that $a_n>0\  \forall\  n\ge1$.
>   Prove or disprove: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent.

I can't show that $a_n > 0\  \forall n\ge1$. I tried using induction but it wouldn't work.

**Attempt:**
$$
\begin{align}
2\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}-\sqrt{n+1}&=(2\sqrt{n}-(\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1}))\cdot {2\sqrt{n}+(\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1})\over2\sqrt{n}+(\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1})}\\&={2n-2\sqrt{n-1}\cdot\sqrt{n+1}\over2\sqrt{n}+(\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1})}\end{align}$$
(The calculations are true for sure. No check is desired.)
Denote
$$a_n=2\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}-\sqrt{n+1}={2n-2\sqrt{n-1}\cdot\sqrt{n+1}\over2\sqrt{n}+(\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1})}\text{ and }b_n={1\over n^{2}}.$$

Then 
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_n\over b_n} & =\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{2}{2n-2\sqrt{n-1}\cdot\sqrt{n+1}\over2\sqrt{n}+(\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1})} \\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{2}\lim_{n\to \infty}{2n-2\sqrt{n-1}\cdot\sqrt{n+1}\over2\sqrt{n}+(\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1})} \\
&=0
\end{align*}$$
By the comparison test for series convergence, since $\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_n\over b_n}=0$, then if $b_n$ converges, which it does, so does $a_n$.

Comment: You're overcomplicating things. See that $S_n = 1 + \sqrt n - \sqrt{n+1} \to 1$ as by the argument in my answer.

Comment: I am sorry. We didn't learn much about telescoping series.

Comment: No problem. Note how you can justify the telescoping property by "guessing" what telescopes. Also note that you have some notational problems in the $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ part, you can't write $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2 \lim_{n\to\infty} \ldots = 0$ because the first limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will address both parts of your question:

**Part 1:** Proving that $a_n>0$.

From your final form of $a_n$

$$a_n=\frac{2n-2\sqrt{(n-1)(n+1)}}{2\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1}}$$

we can notice that the denominator is always positive (when $n\ge1$), so it remains to show that $2n>2\sqrt{(n-1)(n+1)}=2\sqrt{n^2-1}$. This is quite easy (thanks to Steven Stadnicki for pointing this out):

$$n^2>n^2-1\implies n>\sqrt{n^2-1}\implies2n>2\sqrt{n^2-1}$$
as desired.

**Part 2:** Proving that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges by the limit comparison test.

Unfortunately your solution is not quite correct as there is an error in your limit computation, and you should get $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^2a_n=\infty$ which doesn't work for us. However, we can instead use $n^{3/2}$, and find that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^{3/2}a_n=\frac{1}{4}$, which proves the sum converges because $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ converges.

**Limit Computations:**

First we note

$\begin{align}a_n&=\frac{2n-2\sqrt{(n-1)(n+1)}}{2\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1}}
\\&=\frac{2\left(n-\sqrt{n^2-1}\right)}{2\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1}}
\\&=\frac{2\left(n-\sqrt{n^2-1}\right)}{2\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1}}\times\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2-1}}{n+\sqrt{n^2-1}}
\\&=\frac{2}{\left(2\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1}\right)\left(n+\sqrt{n^2-1}\right)}
\end{align}$

Hence

$\begin{align}\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^2a_n&=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2n^2}{\left(2\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1}\right)\left(n+\sqrt{n^2-1}\right)}
\\&=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2\sqrt{n}}{\left(2+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}\right)}
\\&=\infty
\end{align}$

while

$\begin{align}\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{3/2}a_n&=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2n^{3/2}}{\left(2\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1}\right)\left(n+\sqrt{n^2-1}\right)}
\\&=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2}{\left(2+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}\right)}
\\&=\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}$

Comment: An even easier way than the AGM to show that $2n\gt 2\sqrt{(n-1)(n+1)}$: use a little basic algebra on the latter.  The inequality is $2\sqrt{n^2}\gt2\sqrt{n^2-1}$, which is pretty trivial to see.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Whoops, of course, thank you. It seems that I was too seduced by AM-GM to notice the simple way.

Comment: Believe me, I know that feeling!  It's a fine tool, but sometimes it's your hammer...

Comment: Great! There is a test though, using 0 as a limit http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/limit_comparison.html 
I understand exactly where I was wrong. :)
You shall receive the bounty as soon as possible.

Comment: @Meitar Oh, sorry, I didn't know about the tests for the $0$ and $\infty$ cases. Thanks for the link! (I'll remove that part from my answer).

Comment: Shouldn't it be "$\begin{align}\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2n\sqrt{n}}{\left(2+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}\right)}
\\&=\infty
\end{align}$" after you divide by $\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: @Meitar I actually divided by $\sqrt{n}$ and $n$ in the same step. I divided the left hand term by $\sqrt{n}$ and the right hand term by $n$ in the denominator.

Comment: Oh silly me... You are right...

Answer (score 4):

$$a_{n}=\left(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}\right)-\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: How did you get to this form? 
I would have never thought of that by myself... Is there any system?

Comment: @Meitar Everyone that does this have seen it from someone before. You have seen it now. The pattern is a difference of square roots. The trick is to multiply and divide by their sum.

Comment: Okay... I tried it with conjugate multiplication and it worked.

Comment: How is my attempt added after edit? I really wanted to prove this by comparison test.

Answer (score 2):

We have, $$a_n=2\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}-\sqrt{n+1} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n-1}} -  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} \ge 0$$

and $\displaystyle \sum a_n$ telescoping!

Comment: How is my attempt added after edit? I really wanted to prove this by comparison test.  
Yes, I know it is telescoping but I didn't want this way...

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to see the formula. The $n$th term of the sequence is of the form $f(n+1) - 2f(n) + f(n-1)$, where $f(n) = -\sqrt{n}$.

This is a "difference of differences"; $f(n+1) - 2f(n) + f(n-1) = g(n+1) - g(n)$, where $g(n) = f(n) - f(n-1)$. So the infinite sum is telescoping and will equal $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g(n) - g(1)$ once you show the limit exists.

---

I thought of a less tricky way to show this. Write
$$a_n = 2\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}-\sqrt{n+1} = \sqrt{n}\bigg(2 - \sqrt{1 - {1 \over n}} - \sqrt{1 + {1 \over n}}\bigg)$$
Use Taylor series on the square roots to get
$$a_n =  \sqrt{n}\bigg[2 - \bigg(1 - {1 \over 2n} + O\bigg({1 \over n^2}\bigg)\bigg) - \bigg(1 + {1 \over 2n} + O\bigg({1 \over n^2}\bigg)\bigg)\bigg]$$
$$= \sqrt{n} O\bigg({1 \over n^2}\bigg)$$
$$= O\bigg({1 \over n^{3/2}}\bigg)$$
Thus the series converges in comparison with $\displaystyle{\sum_n {1 \over n^{3/2}}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from my answer to [this near-duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114819/sum-1n-2-sqrtn-sqrtn-1-sqrtn1-converge-or-not):
**Hint**
It's a telescoping sum. With $a_n := \sqrt n - \sqrt{n+1}$, $a_n - a_{n-1} = 2\sqrt n - \sqrt{n-1} - \sqrt{n+1}$ so
$$\sum_{i=1}^n 2\sqrt i - \sqrt{i-1} -\sqrt{i+1} = 1 + \sqrt n - \sqrt{n+1} \stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 1$$
This even allows you to obtain the value.

Answer (score 0):

Write $$a_n = \frac {4} {(2 \sqrt {n} + \sqrt {n - 1} + \sqrt {n + 1}) (2n + 2 \sqrt {n^2 - 1})} \sim \frac {1} {4 n \sqrt {n}}.$$ Then, $$\sum a_n \sim \frac {1} {4} \zeta (\frac {3} {2}).$$